# How can i convert the mongoose aggregation array of object of object response into json object response

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I have you mongoose aggregation in nodejs to get the multiple distinct values of the documents. The response I got is an array of the object of objects. How can convert that into a general JSON object response?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lean()` function exposed by mongoose

And example would be:

```
YourModel.find().lean().exec(function (err, users) {
    return res.end(users);
}
```

OR

```
const leanDoc = await MyModel.findOne().lean();
```

> Enabling the lean option tells Mongoose to skip instantiating a full Mongoose document and just give you the POJO.

Doc Link: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html#using-lean